# Weird behavior if() with false statement evaluates to true C#

Tags: c#

In few words: an **if** statement evaluating a statement as **false** is executing the code inside that **if** statement. I have proofs:

**Step 1** My code executes a constructor to create a new instance of irrelevant name class. The constructors receives an string with CSV format as parameter. Then the string is split by ',' and if the number of items in the resulting array is less than **x** an exception should be thrown

[image]

**Step 2**: even when the statement is false the exception is thrown!

[image]

**Step 3** After crying and weeping for a while, I copy the exactly same amount of code a few lines below. Surprise! The code behaves as expected!

[image]

[image]

The images are self explanatory. There is no trick. I am really astonished.

I can work around this simply by having that code in the place where it behaves as expected. But in my opinion the output of a block of code must be independent of its position in a file!

Comment: so, tried to watch the variable?? check them? cause.. it's not reproducible.. so none can't help you..

Comment: In C# it is.  The position in the file is irrelevant.  The position in the ***lexical block*** however is another story.  There are absolutely other factors at play here beyond what you've shown.  You need to post just enough ***code*** to create a minimal, viable, reproduceable example.  Images do not qualify.

Comment: isn't an if statement supposed to have `{` and `}` as statement open and closers as it states in [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5011f09h.aspx)

Comment: @BagusTesa, in fact in the images you can see the watcher I added

Comment: @TravFitzy that isn't a hard requirement in C#.  You can have single line if/else blocks without braces, although braces are usually a recommended coding style.

Comment: @TravFitzy not if you only have one statement inside the if

Comment: @taquion, David L is right. anyway, try to enclose the if with `{` and `}` as Trav Fitzy suggested. although it should not necessary, but it is my habit to enclose `if`s..

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation. @David L I will work to try to make an reproduceable example. I haven't have success so far

Comment: Did you mess around with moving the break point "arrow"? Because both evaluate to false in your viewer. If you comment out the first one doesn't it crash at the second one? It really looks like you've forgotten to write <= but then again, it's your code.

Comment: Where are you creating the object-instance of the class?

Comment: How can your code even reach the second `if` block if the first one is throwing an exception? That makes no sense. Are you sure the code you are editing is the code that is running?

Comment: Are you compiling release or debug? The position of the current line when debugging the release build is sometimes wrong. Is the exception actually thrown?  Are you sure that the program you are debugging actually matches the source code that you are looking at?

Comment: @ThomasLindvall I did not mess around the break point. I know that both statements are evaluating to true. Thats why I am asking for help. I don understand why

Comment: @DavidG I can reach that point because while debugging you can move the debugging arrow to "jump" the first if so that it not execute

Comment: 1. Please show where minNumberofItems of Items is defined 
Are you sure you are not getting another exception?

Comment: @EricLippert, I am debugging. I think I will record a video and share it in you tube. I am completly sure that the code I am debugging matches the code I am looking at

Comment: Close VS, reopen it, clean the build and try again.

Comment: @DavidG so far I have restarted VS twice, cleaning the solution and rebuilding, no success

Comment: @DaniDev MinNumberOfItems is a private int const = 6, in fact if I just write the 6 inside the conditional statemen it also fails

Comment: In the VS options, do you have the "Require source files to exactly match the original version" chcecked under Debugging->General?

Comment: yes, I just checked that after your comment

Comment: What does that yellow exclamation point on the top of the scrollbar mean?

Comment: @Tyress that was a warning about me not being connected my microsoft account

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After all the answer was hidden in a comment by @Eric Lippert

> Are you compiling release or debug? The position of the current line when debugging the release build is sometimes wrong. Is the exception actually thrown?

The exception was not thrown really. Although I was debugging the debug build the fact is that the current line entered the if even when the condition statement was false, although the line did not execute.

When debugging I interpreted that that line was next to be executed. Curiously when removing the **try catch** block below then the debugging line step over.

I am really embarrassed with you guys but the fact is that I was so used to be debugging and to consider the highlighted line to be the next to be executed that well...

Nevertheless I would appreciate if someone could explain why this happens.

Comment: Cannot believe I've been struggling with this for two days, and it's because I was debugging in "Release".... Thanks for this answer!

Answer (score 1):

I would refresh those values, maybe you're showing old ones? Close and reload the project, because:

I've just run your test and this is what I got from

**LINQPad**:

[image]

**Visual Studio** (Community edition)

[image]

and even **Visual Studio Code**

[image]

**bottom line:**

The condition `6 < 6` is always evaluated to `false`. And that's correct.

Comment: @taquion his string is not exactly the one in your images, but the old values comment will make sense if it works the second time around. You've probably been messing with the Watch window?

Comment: @balexandre, thanks for your time, I have also created another console project and I can not reproduce the error. I am about recording a video

Comment: Images are bad enough, but a video? Why not some code?

Comment: @Tyress realized that and was updating it when you wrote your comment :)

Answer (score 0):

> @DavidG I can reach that point because while debugging you can move the debugging arrow to "jump" the first if so that it not execute

this is why you're allowed to continue past the first statement and it will skip the second statement as well (there's a lot more going on but it would require a smaller blogpost and me to be Jon Skeet to be able to explain it all).

> @ThomasLindvall I did not mess around the break point. I know that both statements are evaluating to true. Thats why I am asking for help. I don understand why

6 < 6 will never evaluate to true, it's mathematically impossible in Western mathematics (unsure how the Arabic world uses < and > but I've seen some of them do simpler operations from right to left). Look in your viewer "window" beneath your code, it clearly states that it's false.

If you comment out the first line such as;

```
//if(strItems.Length < MinNumberOfItems)
```

you're going to crash on the second line

```
if(strItems.Length < MinNumberOfItems)
```

if you want the MinNumberOfItems and the number of items contained in strItems.Length to be able to be equal you need to use the <= operator instead of <.